# How to deploy app to IIS via FTP or FTPS with github actions?

Tags: .net, github, .net-core, github-actions

Need to deploy an app to IIS via FTP with Github actions

Created github action to build and used ftp action to deploy but although first deployment is successful next deploys fail with file cannot be deleted or replaced as it is in use

Answer (score 0):

To Deploy in IIS you need to add a temp file app_offline.htm to stop and restart the application

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/app-offline

```html
# name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to IIS via FTP

   on:
     push:
       branches:
      - main
       workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_to_ftp:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
     
      - name: Publish
        run: |
          dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish --runtime win-x64 --self-contained false
          mkdir stop_app
      - name: Add app_offline
        uses: "finnp/create-file-action@master"
        env:
          FILE_NAME: "./stop_app/app_offline.htm"
      - name: Stop App
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.3
        with:
          # Deployment destination server & path. Formatted as protocol://domain.com:port/full/destination/path/
          ftp-server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
          protocol: ftps
          security: strict
          # FTP account username
          username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
          # FTP account password
          password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
          # The local folder to copy, defaults to root project folder
          local-dir: ./stop_app/
          server-dir: api/          
      - name: FTP Deploy
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.3
        with:
          ftp-server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
          protocol: ftps
          security: strict
          # FTP account username
          username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
          # FTP account password
          password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
          # The local folder to copy, defaults to root project folder
          local-dir: ./publish/
          server-dir: api/
```

Comment: Shouldn't we add a step to remove the file after finishing deployment?